# Use Osborn's Rule to suggest an identity involving cothx^2 and cosechx^2 then to solve

Tags: trigonometry, trigonometric-series

[image: two muppets]

i know 1+cothx^2=cschx^2

but how to suggest the identity then use to solve part b?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you replace $\text{cosech}^2 x$ by $1 + \coth^2 x$, you get a quadratic equation in $\coth x$.

Comment: yeah. i get cothx= -3+-(Sqr17)/2 but how to get x?

Comment: Since $\coth x$ has range $(-\infty,-1)\cup(1,\infty),$ you can rule out $\coth x=\frac{-3+\sqrt{17}}2.$ Hence, $$x=\operatorname{arccoth}\left(\frac{-3-\sqrt{17}}2\right).$$ Now, use the fact that $$\operatorname{arccoth}u=\frac12\ln\left(\frac{u+1}{u-1}\right)$$ for $|u|>1.$ Do you know this fact? If not, you can proceed directly from $$\coth x=\frac{-3-\sqrt{17}}2,$$ since $$\coth x=\frac{e^x+e^{-x}}{e^x-e^{-x}}=\frac{e^{2x}+1}{e^{2x}-1}.$$